# New-TimeSpan cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can i use New-Timespan cmdlet to calculate the total time taken for script execution.I tried a sample like this.

```
$val=Get-Date
$start=New-TimeSpan -Start $val
$val2=Get-Date
$end=New-TimeSpan -End $val2
$diff=New-TimeSpan -Start $start -End $end
```

But ended up with following error: New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'Start'. Cannot convert the "00:00:08.7110000" value of type "System.TimeSpan" to
type "System.DateTime".

Comment: The simplest solution is in the accepted answer, but to explain why your attempt failed: the `-Start` and `-End` parameters of the [`New-TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) cmdlet require `[datetime]` , not `[timespan]` arguments, i.e. _points in time_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `New-TimeSpan` just subtract the `DateTime` objects:

```
$script_start = Get-Date
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$script_end = Get-Date
$script_end - $script_start
```

This will create a `TimeSpan` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Measure-Command`. It returns a timespan object. Example:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command -Expression {1..10000000}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 714
Ticks             : 17149279
TotalDays         : 1.98487025462963E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000476368861111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.0285821316666667
TotalSeconds      : 1.7149279
TotalMilliseconds : 1714.9279
```