# Need an updated method for New-Timespan cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We are using a powershell script cobbled together from other entries here / spiceworks. After moving this to a newer server, theres some difference somewhere we cannot find and the get timespan line is resulting in the following error:

```
New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'End'. Cannot convert the "60.00:00:00" value of type "System.TimeSpan" to type "System.DateTime".
At C:\ExpirationScript\PasswordChangeNotification.ps1:61 char:54
+     $daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
```

Tried a few different ideas found on stackoverflow to replace this variable without success:

```
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days`
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Script being used:

```
# Please Configure the following variables....
$smtpServer="localhost"
$expireindays = 7
$from = "contact@domain.com"
$logging = "Enabled" # Set to Disabled to Disable Logging
$logFile = "c:\pathtoscripting\ADpasscheck.csv" # ie. c:\mylog.csv
$testing = "Disabled" # Set to Disabled to Email Users
$testRecipient = "testuser@ITdomain.com"
$nullRecipient = "failoverrecipient@domain.com"
$date = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy
$exemptUsers = "Administrator"
#
############################################################################

# Check Logging Settings
if (($logging) -eq "Enabled")
{
    # Test Log File Path
    $logfilePath = (Test-Path $logFile)
    if (($logFilePath) -ne "True")
    {
        # Create CSV File and Headers
        New-Item $logfile -ItemType File
        Add-Content $logfile "Date,Name,EmailAddress,DaystoExpire,ExpiresOn"
    }
} # End Logging Check

# Get Users From AD who are Enabled, Passwords Expire and are Not Currently Expired #Enabled was missing from this line so disabled accounts were being found
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = get-aduser -filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress
$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge

# Process Each User for Password Expiry
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    If ($exemptUsers -contains $user.SamAccountName) { Continue; }
    $Name = (Get-ADUser $user | foreach { $_.Name})
    $emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
    $passwordSetDate = (get-aduser $user -properties * | foreach { $_.PasswordLastSet })
    $PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
    # Check for Fine Grained Password
    if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
    {
        $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
    }
 
    $expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
    $today = (get-date)
    $daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
       
    # Set Greeting based on Number of Days to Expiry.

    # Check Number of Days to Expiry
    $messageDays = $daystoexpire

    if (($messageDays) -ge "1")
    {
        $messageDays = "in " + "$daystoexpire" + " days."
    }
    else
    {
        $messageDays = "today."
    }
}
```

Tried reworking line to use other idea found here (date time object) but could not incorporate properly:
[New-TimeSpan cmdlet in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663172/new-timespan-cmdlet-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're expecting `$expireson` to be a `[datetime]` instance, but it is a `[timespan]` instance**, which is why the call to [`New-TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan) fails (the `-Start` and `-End` arguments must be `[datetime]` instaces, i.e. *points in time*).

Given how you set the value of `$expireson`:

```
$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
```

the **implication is that `$passwordsetdate` is `$null`** - which, in effect, makes the assignment equivalent to `$expireson = $maxPasswordAge`, i.e. stores the `[timespan]` value contained in `$maxPasswordAge` in `$expireson`.

Only if `$passwordsetdate` contained a `[datetime]` instance would the `+` operation work as intended, i.e. it would add the `[timespan]` value to the `[datetime]` instance to yield a new *`[datetime]`* instance.

Simple examples:

```
# OK: Adds the timespan to the date and returns the resulting date, 
#     i.e. [datetime] '1970/01/02'
[datetime] '1970/01/01' + [timespan]::FromDays(1)

# !! BROKEN: because $allegedDate is $null, the timespan is used as-is.
$allegedDate = $null
$allegedDate + [timespan]::FromDays(1)
```

---

Therefore:

- You **must ensure that `$passwordsetdate` contains the intended `[datetime]` value**.

  - I'm not familiar enough with AD to know under what circumstances the value is `$null`, but based on [this ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/q/819632/176094), two factors may be at play:

    - Running *with elevation* may be necessary.
    - `$null` may be returned if the user will have to change their password on next login.
- You can then **simply *directly subtract* your two `[datetime]` instances** from each other - no need for `New-TimeSpan`:

  ```
  $daystoexpire = ($expireson - $today).Days
  ```